# Text books on computability

Tags: reference-request, computability, big-list, book-recommendation, turing-machines

I collected the following "top eight" text books on computability (in alphabetical order):

- Boolos et al., [Computability and Logic](http://books.google.com/books?id=kKPA1DF-g44C)
- Cooper, [Computability Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=SJvt8ELnMakC)
- Davis, [Computability and unsolvability](http://books.google.com/books?id=nbOqAAAAQBAJ)
- Hermes, [Enumerability, decidability, computability](http://books.google.com/books?id=UYWUmQEACAAJ)
- Hopcroft et al., [Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Automata_Theory,_Languages,_and_Computation) 
  *(thanks to Bill Province)*
- Kleene, [Introduction to Metamathematics](http://books.google.com/books?id=4RGCMQEACAAJ)
- Minsky, [Computation](http://books.google.com/books?id=8y9PngEACAAJ)
- Sipser, [Introduction to the Theory of Computation](http://books.google.com/books?id=1aMKAAAAQBAJ)
  *(thanks to Prajwal Kansakar)*

I know it's opinion-based, but which important text books did I miss?

Comment: What level of text books are you after? This will have a significant effect on whether these are the "top seven"...

Comment: Introductory and the next level.

Comment: One trouble is that such a list is too broad. Kleene's 1950 book is really a graduate-level reference, and is quite "classic" at this point; it isn't really useful as a textbook at any level. On the other hand Hopcroft and Ullman, and Sipser, are much more "computer science" texts than "computability theory" texts.  Also, should this question have the big-list tag?

Comment: @CarlMummert: What's the "real" difference between "computer science" and "computability theory"? "Computers" and "computability" are obviously strongly interrelated, and so are "science" and "theory". The main delta is "practice" or "application" (between "science" and "theory").

Answer (score 10):

[Cutland, Computability (CUP).](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/computer-science/programming-languages-and-applied-logic/computability-introduction-recursive-function-theory?format=PB?format=PB) A beautifully lucid and elegant classic text.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say that [[Odifreddi 1989]](http://store.elsevier.com/product.jsp?isbn=9780444894830) is still a good text to have, to use it at least as a reference book (but pretty good as a textbook too, I found).

One can also take a look at Peter Smith's ["Teach yourself logic guide"](http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/), where different sources are cited and commented upon. It covers much more than just computability, though there's a section exclusively on it (edit: now that I checked it again, there are actually *two* sections: 5.3 and 7.3 in the current version).

Answer (score 5):

Michael Sipser, Theory of Computation. One of the best that is out there.

Comment: I will proceed as with other answers (to keep a comprehensive list).

Comment: This book has to be approached with care. The basic topics of computability theory are Turing computability (including the recursion theorem) and Turing reductions; Sipser considers the latter an "advanced topic" and discusses it for one page. The book is an excellent book for its intended audience, but it is not really a book in computability theory.

Comment: I am one more vote for Sipser. Not the best introductory text in my opinion, but an excellent work on the subject of computability.

Answer (score 4):

The following book is also quite famous I think:

Soare, R. (1987) [Recursively enumerable sets and degrees](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=9I7Pl00LU5gC&dq=recursively%20enumerable%20sets%20and%20degrees%20soare&hl=fr&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

Here are two others about the interaction between computability and algorithmic randomness:

Nies, A. (2009) [Computability and Randomness](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=cKqZHA76-BcC&dq=nies%20computability%20and%20randomness&hl=fr&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

Downey, R. Hirschfeldt, D. (2010) [Algorithmic Randomness and Complexity](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=FwIKhn4RYzYC&dq=downey%20hirschfeldt%20algorithmic%20randomness%20complexity&hl=fr&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

Answer (score 4):

Some times ago, it was very popular :

- Hartley Rogers, [Theory of Recursive Functions and Effective Computability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262680521) (1967).

Answer (score 3):

Hopcraft, Motwani and Ullman, [Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Automata_Theory,_Languages,_and_Computation)

Comment: Bingo! I added this.

Comment: May I add that one needs to distinguish between the first and second editions of this book as the later is a considerably ``trimmed down'' version of the former.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely add [Godel, Escher, Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach) (Hofstadter, 1979) to this list. It is a fascinating book that touches topics from computability, such as recursive and recursively enumerable sets / languages. I read GEB while taking a course on Computability and Complexity in university, and it was a great decision. Hofstadter does a great job explaining mind-boggling topics from computability theory and connecting them to seemingly unrelated stuff.

Comment: It is definitely not a _textbook_, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm 100％ agree. But it helped me to understand some of the topics better than any textbook out there

Answer (score 1):

My undergraduate course, which was cross-listed with a graduate course, used Davis, Sigal, and Weyuker's *Computability, Complexity, and Languages*. It's billed as introductory, but I found it terse and I think it would be a very difficult introduction without a [very good professor](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~case/). However, it does cover a lot in a rigorous mathematical manner. I had the impression it was well regarded, but I don't see it mentioned much.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new 2016 edition of Soare's book, now called [Turing Computability: Theory and Applications](https://g.co/kgs/sMhqBb)

Answer (score 1):

Soare's old book(mentioned above) is perhaps the most well known text about c.e. (formerly r.e.) languages.

Soare's new book, Turing Computability: Theory and Applications, is very dense but covers many areas and should be used as a refrence.