# Textbooks on Theoretical Computer Science

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, book-recommendation, formal-languages, automata

What graduate level textbooks would you recommend on subjects like Formal Language (Automata) Theory and Complexity + Computability Theory for someone from a math background wanting to look into the deeper, more philosophical aspects?

Comment: I'm not sure what books you think will "spare the hard stuff". Computer Science is a deep field with lots of hard problems, and the techniques reflect this. That said, you can find a long list of books on automata, complexity, and computability [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962414/text-books-on-computability).

Comment: When I was a math undergraduate, I took a few courses in theoretical CS. I really enjoyed the first edition of the book on automata by Hopcroft and Ullman. I'm not sure if it's not advanced enough or out of date now.